# how to download video by select by tag with BeautifulSup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I try to download video from a site with a python script.
The objective is to retrieve the video contained in the div tag '_2nCkU'.
The answer of python is "none". Could you help me to see the problem please ?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*-coding:Utf-8 -*
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
username = raw_input('Username : ')
url = 'https://www.website.com/add/' + str(username)

mozhdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.0.3) Gecko/2008092417 Firefox/3.0.3'}
requete = requests.get(url, headers=mozhdr)
page = requete.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
div = soup.find('div', {'id': '_2nCkU'})

print(div)
```

Comment: What kind of video is it ?

Comment: It's mp4 video.

Comment: Why are you using `raw_input` with Python 3?

Comment: I start in python, I still discover

Comment: @PxL It doesn't say what kind of HTML you have ?

Comment: @Zulu, Sorry I don't know how to answer to that question, html it seems. I try to catch the video from snapchat.com. The tag is <video src="blob:https://www.snapchat.com/......." playsinline=""></video>